# An error occures everytime I duplicate my Rocky Linux vmdk

Tags: linux, virtualbox, clone

I have recently studied Rocky Linux (the really basics) and sometimes I "mess" with the OS (doing some experiments to learn about it and how it works). In order to not install it on an actual pc, I install it on a VirtualBox, and in order to not be forced to go through the installation every time, I cloned a fresh installation into a `vmdk` file, so when everytime things are going bad, I can simply use this clone and continue without having to re-install it.

When I type the `pvs`, `vgs` or `lvs` command(s), I get an error, [Which I already found a way to solve](https://serverfault.com/questions/1093110/linux-lvm-pvid-last-seen-on):

```
Devices file sys_wwid t10.ATA_____VBOX_HARDDISK___________________________VB7f1e0511-0347cdea_ PVID bpNp2fn5ADn82LP89ic7346tJcwqJkG6 last seen on /dev/sda2 not found.
```

However, I do not understand why does it happens (I mean, It happens even when I make an `ova` file!), and when I tried to remove this PVID, I got a warning message:

```
[root@localhost ~]# lvmdevices --delpvid bpNp2fn5ADn82LP89ic7346tJcwqJkG6
  Devices file sys_wwid t10.ATA_____VBOX_HARDDISK___________________________VB7f1e0511-0347cdea_ PVID bpNp2fn5ADn82LP89ic7346tJcwqJkG6 last seen on /dev/sda2 not found.
Device /dev/sda2 is used by an active LV, continue to remove? n
  Device not removed.
```

This is confusing. I have typed "y" once and nothing bad happend (the system still works), but I don't know why all of this happens in every clone.

**Update**, this is how it looks like after the reboot:
login as: root
root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
Activate the web console with: systemctl enable --now cockpit.socket

```
Last login: Mon Apr 24 16:21:58 2023 from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
[root@localhost ~]# lvs
[root@localhost ~]# pvs
[root@localhost ~]# vgs
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Disk model: VBOX HARDDISK
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6d59c969

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048  2099199  2097152   1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       2099200 41943039 39843840  19G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/rl-root: 17 GiB, 18249416704 bytes, 35643392 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rl-swap: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

(As you can see, `lvs`, `pvs` and `vgs` returns... Nothing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of frustrating days, I have found out what I've done wrong.

I have used a Full Cloning method, Instead of Linked Cloning. When I did that, the UUID of the VMDK file changed, and the Rocky Linux system is used to the original UUID, so the new machine was "corrupt" and had no LVMs.

The "Full Cloning" is also like if I was copying the VMDK file (without the other configuration files) and then attach the copied VMDK file to a new machine, or if I was exporting the VM using VBox's Export Method (to OVA) and then re-importing.

If someone will experience this problem in the future, My solution is:

1. Installing Rocky Linux (I prefer the text-mode, but choose whatever you want)
2. Once the installation is done, Shut down the VM (in text-mode: alt+tab and then the `shutdown -P +0`)
3. Navigate to the VirtualBox directory (e.g.: `C:\Users\<your username>\VirtualBox VMs`) and find your virtual machine directory (e.g.: "`rocky-9.1-x86_64-dvd`")
4. Make a Backup of the machine (Can be used on another hosts!) - Compress the entire directory (recommended with 7z), and save the backup somewhere (I saved it on my NAS server). You don't know if and when you'll need it.
5. In VirtualBox Manager, Select the machine, Use the clone wizard to clone the machine in "Linked Clone" method, Make sure that the "additional options" checkboxes ("Keep Disk Names" & "Keep Hardware UUIDs") are unchecked; **It is also recommended to change the MAC addresses**.
6. Whenever you want to use this machine, Extract the 7z on another host, and use the "Add" button of VBox to load the `.vbox` file in the extracted directory. The machine should work like it was on the original host (Unless you need to make some changes in the Settings, depends on the new host and the old one). Then you can just  repeat step 5 :)

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox is changing drive identifiers when cloning drives because that's what it's internally using to distinguish them. Your clones appear to have different drives in them and LVM correctly recognizes that the original drive is missing.

VirtualBox actually has a built-on feature for achieving what you want: snapshots. Make a snapshot of a known good VM. You'll be able to rollback later. Snapshotting doesn't clone drives, so it doesn't change their ID and doesn't waste host's disk space.

Actually you're kind of already using this feature, because VirtualBox creates a snapshot when making a linked clone. The clone actually builds upon that snapshot, while the original VM can be independently modified.

Answer (score 0):

ISSUE:
The cloned VM had a mismatched serial number for the hard disk, causing LVM to encounter recognition problems.

SOLUTION:

1. Identify the correct serial number of the hard disk using the command `lsblk -o NAME,MODEL,SERIAL` to list block devices along with their models and serial numbers.
   Locate the correct serial number for the cloned disk.
2. Update the serial number in the `/etc/lvm/devices/systemdevices` file to reflect the correct serial number for the cloned disk.
   IDTYPE=sys_wwid IDNAME=t10.ATA_VBOX_HARDDISK_VB<correct_serial_number> DEVNAME=/dev/sda2 PVID= PART=2

   Replace `<correct_serial_number>` with the actual values obtained from the `lsblk` command.

In the provided example, the change was made

From:

`IDTYPE=sys_wwid IDNAME=t10.ATA_VBOX_HARDDISK_VBa0cd5ac0-b51def01 DEVNAME=/dev/sda2 PVID=jTccnAUtUAACo2ye9I22IlFO0wThNegN PART=2`

To:

`IDTYPE=sys_wwid IDNAME=t10.ATA_VBOX_HARDDISK_VB569d205b-20417ce8 DEVNAME=/dev/sda2 PVID= jTccnAUtUAACo2ye9I22IlFO0wThNegN PART=2`

This change ensures that the LVM system recognizes the correct serial number for the cloned hard disk based on the information obtained from `lsblk`.